# Git options not visible on Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I have used Git plugin 3.0.4 for Jenkins version 2.7.4 and also placed all dependency plugins.

- workflow-scm-step (version:1.14.2)
- credentials (version:2.1.8)
- git-client (version:2.1.0)
- mailer (version:1.18)
- matrix-project (version:1.7.1)
- promoted-builds (version:2.27, optional)
- scm-api (version:2.0.2)
- ssh-credentials (version:1.12)
- token-macro (version:1.12.1, optional)
- parameterized-trigger (version:2.4, optional)

But still no Git options are visible on Jenkins in global as well as project configuration. Please provide some suggestions.

Comment: What do the Jenkins logs say at startup?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes plugins are not compatible so try to downgrade git plugin and check again.
I hope it should work.